# Why is an Unreachable code error in this sequence of code and not the latter?

Tags: java, unreachable-code

```
public String motorNoise() {
    String[] ignition={"vroom","pop","bang"};
    engineNoise=(int)(Math.random()*3);
    startEngine=ignition[engineNoise];
    if (engineNoise==2)
        System.out.println("This car needs a service");
    return startEngine;
    
        
    }
```

But this sequence causes an Unreachable code error. Why is the location of the If statement causing the method to fail?

```
public String motorNoise() {
    String[] ignition={"vroom","pop","bang"};
    engineNoise=(int)(Math.random()*3);
    startEngine=ignition[engineNoise];
    
    return startEngine;
    
    if (engineNoise==2)
        System.out.println("This car needs a service");
        
    }
```

Comment: Because you always exit the method via `return startEngine` in the second example. So the `if` statement will never be executed. This is what the "Unreachable code" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Does this answer your question ?  https://www.javatpoint.com/return-statement-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Because in the first example, if you take all possible paths through the method, all statements will be executed.

However, in your second example, the `if` statement can never be executed:

```
public String motorNoise() {
    String[] ignition={"vroom","pop","bang"};
    engineNoise=(int)(Math.random()*3);
    startEngine=ignition[engineNoise];
    
    return startEngine; // <-- EXECUTED UNCONDITIONALLY, FUNCTION TERMINATES
    
    if (engineNoise==2)
        System.out.println("This car needs a service");        
}
```

`return startEngine` is always executed unconditionally and immediately terminates execution of the function. There's no way for `if (engineNoise == 2)` to be executed.

NB. It *always* pays off to properly format and indent your code and to use braces. Your first example

```
public String motorNoise() {
    String[] ignition={"vroom","pop","bang"};
    engineNoise=(int)(Math.random()*3);
    startEngine=ignition[engineNoise];
    if (engineNoise==2)
        System.out.println("This car needs a service");
    return startEngine;
}
```

Is actually:

```
public String motorNoise() {
    String[] ignition={"vroom","pop","bang"};
    engineNoise=(int)(Math.random()*3);
    startEngine=ignition[engineNoise];
    if (engineNoise==2) {
        System.out.println("This car needs a service");
    }
    return startEngine;
}
```

so it is not only the order of lines, but the nesting of your code blocks that affects execution. Anything inside the body of an if-statement is only executed conditionally.

Comment: That's much clearer, I appreciate your help